# How to improve SQL query for pagination?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I’m working with the database and servlets, there was such a problem. I need to receive data from the database of 6 pieces per page, for this I made such a request

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS 'count' 
FROM product
INNER JOIN product_category
  on product.product_category_id = product_category.id 
INNER JOIN  company_manufacturer_product 
  on product.company_manufacturer_product_id =
     company_manufacturer_product.id
GROUP BY 1 LIMIT 6 OFFSET 0;
```

where 6 is the maximum number of items per page and 0 is the page number multiplied by the maximum quantity of goods. But with such an implementation on the second page I have duplicate products how can i improve it?

The part of the code where I form the request:

```
StringBuilder startResponse = new StringBuilder("SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM product " +
                "INNER JOIN product_category on product.product_category_id = product_category.id " +
                "INNER JOIN company_manufacturer_product on product.company_manufacturer_product_id=company_manufacturer_product.id");
if (nonNull(form.getProductMax()) && nonNull(form.getPage())) {
            startResponse.append(" LIMIT ").append(form.getProductMax()).append(" OFFSET ").append(form.getPage() * form.getProductMax());
        }
```

My database respone without LIMIT and OFFSET:

[image]

My database respone when I use the query that described above, this request is sent to the database when I turn to the first page with the goods:
[image]

When I turn to the second page with goods, I send such a request to the database

```
SELECT * , COUNT(*) AS 'count' 
FROM product 
INNER JOIN product_category
  on product.product_category_id = product_category.id
INNER JOIN company_manufacturer_product 
  on product.company_manufacturer_product_id = 
     company_manufacturer_product.id
GROUP BY 1 LIMIT 6 OFFSET 6;
```

and i have response like that:

[image]

I can not understand what the problem is. I have to use requests through COUNT! How prove it?

Comment: Perhaps try adding an ORDER BY clause to your query. By the way, if "id" is your primary key then `GROUP BY 1` is not useful and `COUNT(*)` will always be 1.

Comment: Yes, thank you its helped me

Comment: Pagination without `ORDER BY` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Anytime you find yourself with `*` and GROUP BY in the same query, you've already lost. If it was me, I'd start over. Get a properly working query, then look at the likely size of the data set, then talk about pagination

Answer (score 0):

Not against the solution of this question, according to the above method, adding `order by` to original sql can solve the problem. 
But I think I have a better practice for pagination: using parameters like `has_more`, `last_product_id` and `limit_num` to connect clients with server.

`has_more` indicates more data in server whether or not left;
`last_product_id` indicates the id of last response data;
`limit_num` indicates the number of per page.

So, client can using `has_more` to determine sending a request or not, if it is, client sends a request with `last_product_id` and `limit_num` to server; and for server, the sql can be this:

```
select * from table where id < $last_product_id order by id desc
limit $limit_num + 1; =>$datas
```

And, count($datas) and $limit_num to calculate the value of `has_more` and `last_product_id`:

```
$has_more = 0;
$data_num = count($datas);
if ($data_num > $page_limit) {
    $has_more = 1;
    array_pop($datas);
    $data_num--;
}

$last_product_id = end($datas)['id'] ?? 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

> SELECT *, COUNT(product.id) AS 'count' FROM product INNER JOIN
>   product_category on product.product_category_id = product_category.id
>   INNER JOIN company_manufacturer_product on
>   product.company_manufacturer_product_id=company_manufacturer_product.id
>   group by product.id order by product.id LIMIT 6 OFFSET 0;